# How does a database sequence manages a race condition?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, rdbms, race-condition

I am writing an application which will be deployed on n number of nodes. The applications entity classes used the SEQUENCE generation strategy to generate the primary keys. Since, there would be bulk inserts; we shall be giving an allocation size as well.

The concern is when the application will be deployed on n nodes and if two nodes simultaneously requests next sequence from the defined sequence in database:

1. Wouldn't there be any race condition?
2. Or is that sequence also has some light weight locking mechanism to serve the requests sequentially, as it happens in IDENTITY strategy?
3. Or sequence is not the right solution to this problem?

Kindly help. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Think of Sequence as a table with one column storing an integer representing the current id. Each time you insert a new entry, the next operations happen in a **transaction**:

- The current value from SEQUENCE table is read
- That value is assigned as ID to the new entry
- The value from SEQUENCE is incremented

To answer your questions

1. The concurrency issues are addressed by the database.
2. Since inserts happen in a transaction (both simple and bulk inserts), the consistency on ID generation is enforced by the database engine via transactions (by the isolation level of the transaction to be more precise). Make sure your database engine supports transactions.
3. Sequence is the right solution, assuming your database engine supports transactions.

Comment: When we name a sequence in hibernate, we do not give any ISOLATION level there: @SequenceGenerator(name="book_generator", sequenceName = "book_seq", allocationSize=50). SO, does it work on the default isolation level of database i.e may be READ_COMMITED in case of oracle? Or can I expect it to fail if I change the ISOLATION level to READ_UNCOMMITTED?

Comment: If the isolation level is not specified, as you pointed out, it will default to the default level for the database. I would expect it to potentially fail if you would change the default to READ_UNCOMMITTED, but that would be a miss configuration, because in your scenario you clearly need at least write locks enforced by the database.

Comment: Good Answer. You might add a note explaining that because of txn-rollbacks, some numbers in the sequence may go unused. There will be “holes” in the series of numbers stored in your data. This is a feature, not a bug.  But for something like invoice numbers you would need another scheme because missing numbers in such a context would be unacceptable to accountants and auditors.

Comment: Thanks Alexorlea. I have got another doubt now if it there is a separate table maintained for sequence and database isolation level determines its consistency in a race scenario, then how is it different from Table strategy, where pessimistic locks are used on id row of the table to put all the transaction in the sequential order?

Comment: In order to enforce the isolation level of the transaction, the database engine uses database locks. The granularity of those locks (weather we lock the table, a range of entries with the table, an entry itself, etc) is the subject of a lot of optimizations and is different from engine to engine. So, if I understood your question correctly, a difference would be the lock granularity.

Comment: Regarding transaction sequential ordering, this is again the job of the database engine. For example, for a READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level, transactions are not required to be executed sequentially (since they can see data that was modified but not yet committed by another transaction).

Comment: For this particular scenario (ID generation), the transactions are required to get sequence IDs serially. A common approach would be the database engine assigning a monotonous and unique identifier to each transaction and allow them to get IDs based on the order of those identifiers.